# Is it possible to find which tables have new data in the last n days?

Tags: mysql, sql

My current project doesn't use any database migrations and so if any changes arise they are found manualy.

Is it possible to find out which tables in a database have new rows that were created in the last n days (for example 7 days)?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Include a defaulted `CreatedAt` date column in every table you create.

Comment: if you have binary logs activated, you could grep them for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a CreatedAt column in each of the tables but not sure how to check every existing table that there is data with a new CreatedAt, and not sure if I need to loop through all possible tables or there is some information_schema magic command that already does what I need?

Comment: @kiradotee No, there is no magic of this kind. Just use your column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Trigger for insert to make a value in the table for 1 as newly inserted or 0 it is inserted before .... its a flag that shows that a new value is added ... and then you can make an update statement to make sure that they are all take 0 value ... so that every time you insert in the table you add this column with 1
Example :

```
id     StudentName    flag
1      Frank          0
2      Andrew         1


insert into tablename(id,StudentName,flag) Values(3,'Alice',1)
```

always make the flag with 1 to know that it is a new record and it is recently added.

```
update tablename set flag = 0
```

this statment to make sure that all is inserted before and it is not new !!

Answer (score 0):

Create A common table Which shows when table Update

Create table TableUpdatedRrecord (Table_Name varchar(max),Flag int,TableCreatedDate DateTime,Modified Date)

Answer (score 0):

First Create table Which Has Record when New Rows were Inserted in table

`Create table TableUpdatedRrecord (Table_Name varchar(max),Flag INT,TableCreatedDate DateTime,Modified DatetIME)`

Now Create a Trigger for each table which is executed when table has a new insert

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CreatedDate datetime 
Set @CreatedDate=(Select t.create_date from sys.tables t where name='TableName')
INSERT INTO TableUpdatedRrecord
           (Table_Name,[Flag],[TableCreatedDate],[Modified])
     VALUES
           ('TableName'
           ,1
           ,@CreatedDate
           ,GetDate())
END